Azure joined Device login issue with External Identity Provider
We are having our own Identity Provider and we have enabled federation in Azure, which login via broswer for office365 everything works fine, whereas when we try to login Azure joined device(Windows 10/11 machine) always getting username or password is wrong. I can verify based on realm authentication was routed to our identity provider by azure. Once the authentication is success our identity provider sends the STS token back to Azure joined device after that we are getting username or password is wrong.
we have enabled WS-Trust and WS-Fed in our identity provider.
Is there I can validate the STS token response? Moreover I dont receive any other logs in that device as well.
same setup works fine with ADFS instead of our identity provider.
With Thanks
Amjath
same setup works fine with ADFS instead of our identity provider.

Check the Azure AD logs for any errors or warnings related to the login issue. Additionally, you may try enabling Azure AD Connect Health for AD FS to monitor the health of the AD FS infrastructure
